# What event is raised on Grid.Children.Add

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0

In my WPF application, I have a single Main window with a Grid. The Login and Shell are 2 separate UserControls added as children to a grid. I need to find out when the Shell is loaded and start a timer from the Main window.

I just need to know as to what event is raised when a UserControl is added using Grid.Children.Add method, so that I can check if Login is loaded or the Shell and start the timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying,
but it sounds like you're looking for the Load event:

```
UserControl MyControl = new UserControl();
MyControl.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MyControl_Loaded);

public void MyControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (((UserControl)sender).IsLoaded)
    { 
        ..... do something
    }
}
```

Hope it helps